# Use cordova in remote app

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I want to use cordoca.js features in a website application.
So i've done cordova android app setup and setted my website as app url in activity with `super.loadUrl(App_Url);`
In remote page i'm waiting for "deviceready" event but it never occur.
I'm using cordova 3.4.
Do you have experience with this task? How i can use cordova feats in website?

Thank you

Comment: Did you add cordova.js into website load from URL.

Comment: Yes, i uploaded cordova.js on my server and used it in my webpage.

Comment: Please check your project or shared structure index.html. Can you mistake? I have been have remote app.